# Pure HTML: How to create this layout without using "float"?

Tags: css, layout, html

I'm trying to create the following layout for my website:

```
<table width="80%" align="center">
    <tr>
        <td width="80%" bgcolor="red">MAIN CONTENT</td>
        <td bgcolor="green">SIDEBAR</td>
    </tr>       
</table>
```

As you would imagine this will create a table that is 80% of the page width and the content area is 80% of that width, while the sidebar fills the rest.

But this time I want to use DIVs or SPANs or basically a TABLEless design. Now, I know I can use two DIVs and use their "float" properties to achieve this but I was hoping to see if there is something more simple and more logical like this:

```
<div align="center" style="width:80%">
    <span style="width:80%;">
        MAIN CONTENT
    </span>
    <span>
        SIDEBAR
    </span>
</div>
```

Unfortunately the above does not work at all and I don't know why. Can someone please show me the purest HTML implementation for it which does not use "float"?

Every site I see on the internet nowadays has at least one sidebar so I'm hoping your answer to this will help a lot of people besides me. Thanks!

Comment: You're using `<span>`s all wrong! They are used to wrap inline content in a non semantic way. To markup a layout, only use divs! (unless you're using html5, use the html5 tags).

Comment: Why don't you want to use floats? Other than the new CSS3 flexbox stuff, you're not going to get away from them so easily.

Comment: @KyleSevenoaks: I tried reading up the difference in DIV and SPAN and it says the only difference is that SPANs have display: inline.

Comment: @Interrobang: I don't want to use floats because using that somehow makes the content to position itself above other content (as if it is being absolutely positioned?)

Comment: @supersan You need to learn about `clear` and use it in combination with `float` to get your desired result. It will "fix" your problem of the content being position out of the layout as if it's absolute.

Comment: @supersan: Exactly, do you know the difference between block and inline elements? Block elements are what is used to layout your page, divide up your content and separate things from each other. Inline elements are things like spans, img, anchors etc. They go inside the content. :)

Comment: Specifically for now try adding `<div style="clear: left;"></div>` after your floating elements. But even if that works for you make sure to read up on `clear`, so you understand what it does.

Comment: @PaulPRO: thank you, I did see that but never used it with float. So, I will try that now and read about it thoroughly now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this without using floats by using *proper markup* and `display: table;`, `display: table-cell;` with CSS.

HTML:

```
<div id="wrap">
      <div id="sidebar">
        I am a sidebar!
      </div>
      <div id="mainContent">
        I am some main content
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#wrap
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 400px;
    display: table;
}

#sidebar
{
    display: table-cell;
    border: 1px dashed #f00;
}

#mainContent
{
    display: table-cell;
    width: 80%;
    border: 1px dashed #0f0;
}
```

But beware, IE7 and lower do not support this CSS.

http://jsfiddle.net/57Fvk/

---

Using almost the same markup (one extra div) you can use floats to create the desired layout also:

HTML

```
<div id="wrap">
      <div id="sidebar">
        I am a sidebar!
      </div>
      <div id="mainContent">
        I am some main content
    </div>
    <div class="clear">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#wrap
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 400px;
}

#sidebar
{
    width: 20%;
    float: left;
    background: #f00;
    height: 100%;
}

#mainContent
{
    width: 80%;
    float: left;
    background: #0f0;
    height: 100%;
}

.clear
{
    clear: both;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/shzLc/

Comment: thank you for the quick answer. I too stumbled upon display: table; during my quest to find the most elegant solution to this. I also learned that as an added advantage it **also fixes** the "vertical-align: middle" thing which does not seem to work otherwise. Two things though. One is that in the list of browser matrix that support it, it does not work for some browsers which my clients would wish to support. And secondly, if I'm going to just hack my DIVs and make them into table-cells, am I better off using TABLEs like I've been doing all my life? But I appreciate the answer

Comment: No, you're not better off using tables. This uses proper, elegant markup that will not fail and is far easier to maintain than an old, ugly table. Tables have their place, but this is not it. There has also been mention of using a clearfix on your floated markup, you should look into this also. I'll update my answer to include it.

Comment: great and thank you again for the help. I've tried researching this a lot but every time I had this lingering doubt in my mind that maybe there is a better solution for doing this (as majority of sites nowadays need this kind layout). Anyway, once I see all the answers on this site, this will thankfully put my mind at rest and I can finally accept that is indeed the best way of doing it which I will now follow too.

Comment: Great, if you're in the mood for accepting things, accepting my answer would be the best way to show your appreciation!  :D

Answer (score 0):

Here's a very simple way to create this layout:

http://jsfiddle.net/e94zc/

HTML:

```
<div id="page">
    <div id="content">
        Content
    </div>
    <div id="sidebar">
        Sidebar
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#page{
    margin: 0 auto;
    width:80%;
    position: relative;
    }
#content{
    width:80%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
}
#sidebar{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 80%;
    width: 20%;
}
```

Comment: hi, this is also a rather good way of doing it.. thanks for sharing! (wish I had the rep points to upvote this answer as well).

Comment: For the record, though, I would choose to use floats for this layout. I can't think of a good reason to avoid them.